# XSLT - How to specify where dot point text will continue on new line

Tags: html, xml, xslt, html-lists, newline

I have the following XML element being converted to HTML by XSLT. My XSLT processor is Microsoft 1.

When I call an element from my XML to be displayed in an `<li></li>` tag in XSLT I want to be able to specify where an individual `<li></li>` text content will continue on a new line once it reaches a certain point.

I tried adding a `<br></br>` into where I wanted the breaks to occur in my XML elements but it just results in a new line having a bullet point next to it which I don't want.

What is the best way to do this?

Here's an example of my code:

XML ELEMENT being called into
`<li></li>.` In this example two `<li></li>` would be created as my XSLT splits the element into different dot points through the ; as a delimitor.

```
<research>Strategies and Approaches to Teaching and Learning Cross Cultures,  Office for Learning and Teaching,  
    LOL - Grant (pre-2013),  2008 - 2052, $90,000;  Parkour strategies and parallel jumps for spatial data monitoring and join processing,  
    Right Wing Politics,  JSA Early Career Artifact - Grant,  2004 - 20010,  $14,0000.
    </research>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Especially this part: "*I want to be able to specify where an individual <li></li> text content will continue on a new line once it reaches a certain point.*" You want to specify this how? And where? Manually? In the source XML document itself?

Comment: Doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Okay. I would like to be able to control what I showed you above for each <li><li> manually, in either the XML or XSLT whichever offers the best possible solution. Does that answer your question more clearly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a short solution that doesn't use any `<xsl:choose>`, `<xsl:when>` or `<xsl:otherwise>`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
    <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="research"/>
    </ul>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="research/text()[normalize-space()]" name="split">
     <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>
     <xsl:if test="normalize-space($pText)">
       <li>
         <xsl:call-template name="replace">
           <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-before(concat($pText, ';'), ';')"/>
         </xsl:call-template>
       </li>
       <xsl:call-template name="split">
         <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText, ';')"/>
       </xsl:call-template>
     </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="replace">
   <xsl:param name="pText"/>
   <xsl:if test="normalize-space($pText)">
       <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($pText, '§'),'§')"/>
       <xsl:if test="contains($pText, '§')">
           <br/>
         <xsl:call-template name="replace">
           <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText, '§')"/>
         </xsl:call-template>
       </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if> 
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on this source XML document** (the originally-provided one with inserted ';' for line item and '§' for newline):

```
<research>Strategies and Approaches to Teaching and Learning Cross Cultures,  Office for Learning and Teaching,  
LOL - Grant (pre-2013),  2008 - 2052, §$90,000;  Parkour strategies and parallel jumps for spatial data monitoring and join processing,  
Right Wing Politics,  JSA Early Career Artifact - Grant,  2004 - 20010,  §$14,0000.
</research>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<ul>
  <li>Strategies and Approaches to Teaching and Learning Cross Cultures,  Office for Learning and Teaching,  
LOL - Grant (pre-2013),  2008 - 2052, <br />$90,000</li>
  <li>  Parkour strategies and parallel jumps for spatial data monitoring and join processing,  
Right Wing Politics,  JSA Early Career Artifact - Grant,  2004 - 20010,  <br />$14,0000.
</li>
</ul>
```

**and this is displayed by the browser as**:

- Strategies and Approaches to Teaching and Learning Cross Cultures,  Office for Learning and Teaching,  
  LOL - Grant (pre-2013),  2008 - 2052, 
  $90,000
- Parkour strategies and parallel jumps for spatial data monitoring and join processing,  
  Right Wing Politics,  JSA Early Career Artifact - Grant,  2004 - 20010,  
  $14,0000.

Answer (score 1):

If you can and want to insert line breaks manually in the source XML document, I would suggest you use some special *string* for this, not a *markup element* such as `<br/>`. Then you can call another recursive template to replace any instances of the special string with a real HTML line break.

For example, using the `§` symbol to indicate a requested line break in the following input **XML**:

```
<research>Strategies and Approaches to Teaching and Learning Cross Cultures,  Office for Learning and Teaching,  
LOL - Grant (pre-2013),  2008 - 2052, §$90,000;  Parkour strategies and parallel jumps for spatial data monitoring and join processing,  
Right Wing Politics,  JSA Early Career Artifact - Grant,  2004 - 20010,  $14,0000.
</research>
```

then, after having your **XSLT** call:

```
<ul>
    <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="research"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</ul>
```

you need to modify the tokenizing template from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29449837/xml-xslt-html-transformation-how-to-split-xml-element-text-into-dot-points) to:

```
<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="';'"/>
        <xsl:variable name="token" select="substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
        <xsl:if test="$token">
            <li>
                <xsl:call-template name="replace">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$token"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </li>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

and add the replacing template:

```
<xsl:template name="replace">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="search-string" select="'§'"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, $search-string)">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, $search-string)"/>
            <br/>
            <xsl:call-template name="replace">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $search-string)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Browsers seem to treat `<br></br>` and `<br/>` differently, although I've never seen one add a new bullet point.  I think `<br/>` will work for your needs.

Comment: <br><br/> lead to XSLT no longer processing, <br/> by itself still had the bullet point.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the output, and what browser you are using to render it?

Comment: imgur.com/Tu4bFSh - picture of output with <br></br> added before $90,000 in XML document. –  rendered in latest Internet explorer

Comment: Can't access imgur from work.  I really meant a sample of the HTML you generated, though.

Comment: Ah okay. I've just tried to get a sample of the HTML, IE and Firefox are not displaying the HTML correctly when I try to view the page source of the XML document. Therefore I'm not sure how I can provide this to you.

Comment: Then show us your XSLT code. Otherwise, we're all just guessing.